# AngularJS - Converitng a string to int

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-show, angular-ng-if, ng-hide

I have  JSON file with a list of strings that contain numbers, e.g

```
{
    "MyAccount": "105"
}
```

On the front end, can i perform a condition on this value? ie:

```
<div ng-if="MyAccount > 100">
   //code ig account greater than 100
</div>
```

Trying to do this without having to write any JS as this ng-if will be within a complex ng-repeat

Ive tried:

```
<div ng-if="parseInt(MyAccount) > 100">
   //code ig account greater than 100
</div>
```

Comment: can you pass as number from backend?

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava - trying to do that at the moment, but if not possible, then this option would have to work

Comment: `<div ng-if="MyAccount > 100">` should work

Comment: try ng-if="+MyAccount > 100" but it work also with string

Comment: Are you applying the value to a variable inside the $scope? You can't just read a JSON file within your template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div ng-if="MyAccount > 100">
```

this should work since javascript can evaluate something like `("6" > 5)` to true.

somehow,

---

you can try something like this,

```
<div ng-if="myfunc(MyAccount)">
```

in the controller,

```
$scope.myfunc = function(myAcc) {
    var intValue = parseInt(myAcc);

    if(intValue > 100) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have this, `<a href="" ng-click="totalAccount = MyAccount +1" ></a>` this should not work because `MyAccount` is `String`. Can we convert `MyAccount` to `int` inside `ng-click` ? thanks!